# Creating Stripe customer with Parse Cloud Code - Android

Tags: android, stripe-payments, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to create a new Stripe customer by sending the required information to Stripe through a Parse Cloud Code function. My methods are as follows:

Android:

```
private void createCustomer(Token token) {
    String token3 = token.getId();

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("email", username);
    params.put("source", token3);
    params.put("name", firstName);
    params.put("objectId", parseID);
    params.put("description", "myExample customer");

    Log.e("createCustomer method", "about to call cloud code function with " + token.getId());
    ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("createCustomer", params, new FunctionCallback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void done(Object object, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, object.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Log.e("createCustomer method", e.toString());
            }
        }
    });

}
```

And the Cloud Code that my method calls to:

```js
var Stripe = require('stripe');
Stripe.initialize(STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

Parse.Cloud.define("createCustomer", function(request, response) { 

    Stripe.Customers.create({
  card: request.params.token,
        description: request.params.description,
        metadata: {
            name: request.params.name,
            userId: request.params.objectId, // e.g PFUser object ID
        }
    }, {
        success: function(httpResponse) {
            response.success(customerId); // return customerId
        },
        error: function(httpResponse) {
            console.log(httpResponse);
            response.error("Cannot create a new customer.");
        }
    });
});
```

When I do this it calls to the Cloud Code just fine, but it triggers the error response "Cannot create a new customer".

If I try to send the token directly (instead of getting the ID value as a string) and send it that way, like so:

```
private void createCustomer(Token token) {
    //String token3 = token.getId();
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("email", username);
    params.put("source", token);
    params.put("name", firstName);
    params.put("objectId", parseID);
    params.put("description", "myExample customer");

    Log.e("createCustomer method", "about to call cloud code function with " + token.getId());
    ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("createCustomer", params, new FunctionCallback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void done(Object object, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, object.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Log.e("createCustomer method", e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It returns this error:

```
01-12 07:31:27.999 16953-16953/com.stripetestapp.main E/createCustomerMethod: com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid type for ParseObject: class com.stripe.android.model.Token
```

So from the above error I understand that sending the pure token is creating an error, however if I send the token ID in its place it also triggers an error (though a different one). I can't help but think that I am missing something obvious here.

**EDIT:** I've tried to convert the token to a String as shown below:

```
    String token3 = token.toString();
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("source", token3);
```

and it still responds with the error response "Cannot create a new customer".

**EDIT2:** The console.log for the cloud code method createCustomer:

> E2016-01-12T21:09:54.487Z]v13 Ran cloud function createCustomer for user 1xjfnmg0GN with:
>     Input: {"description":"myExample customer","email":"cjfj@ncjf.com","name":"hff","objectId":"1xjfnmg0GN","token":"\u003ccom.stripe.android.model.Token@1107376352 id=\u003e JSON: {\n  \"card\": {\n    \"address_city\": null,\n    \"address_country\": null,\n    \"address_line1\": null,\n    \"address_line2\": null,\n    \"address_state\": null,\n    \"address_zip\": null,\n    \"country\": \"US\",\n    \"cvc\": null,\n    \"exp_month\": 2,\n    \"exp_year\": 2019,\n    \"fingerprint\": null,\n    \"last4\": \"4242\",\n    \"name\": null,\n    \"number\": null,\n    \"type\": null\n  },\n  \"created\": \"Jan 12, 2016 1:09:53 PM\",\n  \"id\": \"tok_17SZOnJQMWHHKlPAwdveiUde\",\n  \"livemode\": false,\n  \"used\": false\n}"}
>     Result: Cannot create a new customer.
>   I2016-01-12T21:09:55.274Z]{"name":"invalid_request_error"}

**EDIT3:** It was suggested to change 'source' to 'token' and send the tokenId instead of the token.toString, which worked. I did have to change one other line in my cloud code, changing:

```
success: function(httpResponse) {
        response.success(customerId); // return customerId
```

to

```
success: function(httpResponse) {
        response.success(httpResponse); // return customerId
```

and it worked exactly as required.

Comment: `params.put("source", token);` => try converting the Token to a String. Parse does not know how to accept the `Token` object

Comment: i've edited my post with your suggestion

Comment: That is your error response, not the actual response. Where does `console.log(httpResponse);` show up for that Stripe method?

Comment: I've added it to my post i see a {"name:invalid_request_error"}?

Comment: According to the documentation - "Invalid request errors arise when your request has invalid parameters", so your parameters for card, description, and metadata aren't right.

Comment: That token string doesn't look correct at all `\u003ccom.stripe.android.model.Token@1107376352`

Comment: i'm not sure what the token string is supposed to look like, but i don't think it is a problem with the way i made the token since it gathered the tokenID from it

Comment: I think you should just store the ID of the Token in Parse. When you need the Stripe customer object, query the Stripe API for it using the ID. Otherwise, you are duplicating the data.

Comment: With reference to your error, though. Your `params` map does not contain the `"token"` key, so when you do `Stripe.Customers.create({ card: request.params.token` it will fail. If you rename `"source"` to `"token"`,  and change the value to `token.getId()` maybe it will work

Comment: the above worked! i will accept your answer if you make one

Comment: `function(httpResponse)` the param name is misleading. it is not describing what is passed.

Comment: njzk2 is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Error 1

Parse only know how to save certain Java datatypes (String, int, boolean, etc.), so this error message

`com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid type for ParseObject: class com.stripe.android.model.Token`

Is referring to this code

```
private void createCustomer(Token token) {
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("source", token);
```

**Solution**: Store the token object differently

---

#### Error 2

The Stripe API [expects certain parameters](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#create_customer) and will throw an `invalid_request_error` when [your request has invalid parameters](https://stripe.com/docs/api#errors).

```
Result: Cannot create a new customer.
{"name":"invalid_request_error"}`
```

The reason it you have invalid parameters is because your Java code is putting a `"source"` key into the `param` map (same code as above), but the JavaScript is expecting a key of `"token"` in this code

```
Stripe.Customers.create({
    card: request.params.token,
```

**Solution**: Either rename the `"source"` key in Java to `"token"` or rename the value in JavaScript from `request.params.token` to `request.params.source`.

---

#### Combination of Solutions

Once Error 2 is fixed, you still need to solve Error 1. As I suggested in the comments above, you should just store the ID of the Token in Parse. When you need the Stripe customer object, query the Stripe API for it using the ID. Otherwise, you are duplicating the data.

To do that, if you renamed `"source"` to `"token"` in Java, you can do this

```
private void createCustomer(Token token) {
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("token", token.getId());
```